# What is causing 'Connect failed: Too many connections' on my wordpress site?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Im creating a **login plugin**, I have a MYSQL db connection and use lots of wp functions in relation to the db such as `add_user_meta` as well as a large number of queries etc etc.

Recently, I have been trying to use `wp_authenticate` to check the validity of input login credentials however I have been getting this error upon attempting to log in for testing.

Error:

> Connect failed: Too many connections

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you get a Too many connections error when you try to connect to the mysqld server, this means that all available connections are in use by other clients. (search mysql Too many connections)

Comment: mysql max connections parameter

Comment: Can it be DoS or DDoS?